# Window Management for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, window-manager

Ok, I feel dumb. I've put many hours into this and found nothing, yet.

When I was using Windows I had this little tool called WinSplit Revolution.

What it did was letting you divide your screen into how many and of how much size you choose "virtual monitors". You set one time of you want to divide your monitor, then everytime WinSplit is opened the monitor is automatically divided into Virtual Monitors.

Screenshots: http://www.google.com/images?hl=en&q=winsplit%20revolution&um=1&ie=UTF-8&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&biw=1045&bih=499

I'm now using a 30' which i want almost always divided into 4 equal size "virtual monitors" (plus my mbp 13' those will be 5 1280x800 virtual monitors)

Now I've switched to Mac OS X and can't find anything that does just this efficiently.

I tried Divvy but I found no way to divide my screen into arbitrary "virtual monitors", I need a couple of clicks to select a 3x3 space on a 9x9 grid.

Before starting coding something like this can you tell me if you already know of some software that does window management like this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for, after watching the Divvy screencast it seems to do what you describe. It seems to support keyboard shortcuts, too, to eliminate clicks. Just to set your expectations, as far as I know there's no way to split the screen in such a way that there are multiple menu bars…

Answer (score 2):

As best I understand, you're just looking for Window tiling.

Check out [SizeUp](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/)

I would link to OneThingWell to give them credit, but I'm too new to have two links, so I gave you the pertinent one.

[edit]

It's $13 ($6 more than the commenter who beat me, boo!!).

As an aside, your mention of "a few clicks" via Divvy caught my eye. I don't remember if this was a preference or a boolean enable/disable, but, If the standard Divvy grid isn't suitable, just tap Option to (roughly) cut each block down to 4 quarters, but then starting from a corner has a fairly good amount of granularity.

Answer (score 1):

Look into Apple's Spaces (installed already with OS). It allows you to have 4 or more virtual monitors and you can even assign different applications to different spaces etc. Switches spaces is also easy (there are kbd shortcuts).

Comment: The difference is he has a large screen and wants to see all windows at once. Spaces is for hiding everything but a few windows (perhaps preferable when using smallish screens). The "virtual monitors" aren't even all of the same size.

Answer (score 0):

TwoUp allows you to make a window go in to either a corner of the screen and taking up a quater of the total screen space by dragging the window into the corner of the screen. Therefore, in a way, this allows for four windows to be open taking up the same space each. But when four screens aren't required it is possible to have one screen open and this program also allows side by side screen 'fitting' much the way that windows 7 does. It does however cost $7 for a license but there is a free trial to have a go with. Hope this helps =)

Answer (score 0):

An app I developed, [Optimal Layout](http://most-advantageous.com/optimal-layout/), lets you quickly tile groups of windows to a particular display.

An upcoming update will support fully customizable layouts, but for now it also gives you fine grain control over individual window positioning.